# If $X = U \begin{pmatrix} \Sigma & 0 \\0&0 \end{pmatrix} U^T$, how is $ U \begin{pmatrix} \Sigma^{-1} & 0 \\0&0 \end{pmatrix} U^T$ called?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Assume $X\succeq 0$ and is decomposed as
\begin{align}
X &= U \begin{pmatrix} \Sigma & 0 \\0&0 \end{pmatrix} U^T,
\end{align}
where $U$ is an orthonormal matrix and $\Sigma\succ0$. Is there a name for
\begin{align}
& U \begin{pmatrix} \Sigma^{-1} & 0 \\0&0 \end{pmatrix} U^T?
\end{align}

Comment: This is the inverse of X if U is a unitary matrix

Comment: But $X$ does not have an inverse

Comment: My apologies, consider the projection of X onto the subspace spanned by Sigma (Call this Y). Then your second matrix is the inverse of Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to invert $X$ we get
\begin{align}
X^{-1} &= U \begin{pmatrix} \Sigma & 0 \\0&0 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} U^T,
\end{align}
but the matrix in the middle is not invertible (its determinant equals zero). However if we let

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} \Sigma & 0 \\0&0 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} \Sigma^{-1} & 0 \\0&0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
then we have performed a [pseudo inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Pseudoinverse).